# Clojure, same method call on different Java Objects

Tags: clojure, itext, clojure-java-interop

In this code `headerTable` and `rowsTable` are Java Objects. Here the same method with the same argument is being called on them:

```
(.setHorizontalAlignment headerTable Element/ALIGN_LEFT)
(.setHorizontalAlignment rowsTable Element/ALIGN_LEFT)
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I would think there must be a way to combine the two calls into one somehow. But since this is 'side effecting' code, perhaps not??

I'm thinking of an answer without writing a custom function or macro, something like "just use `juxt` or `comp`", but then maybe I'm being a bit too prescriptive...

**Edit** Type hinting was mentioned by Leonid Beschastny, so just in case it helps, here's the Java method signature:

```
public void setHorizontalAlignment(int horizontalAlignment)
```

And the class is `PdfPTable`, from iText. (This code is being used to create PDF files).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many possible refactorings, one would be

```
(run! #(.setHorizontalAlignment ^PdfPTable % Element/ALIGN_LEFT)
      [headerTable rowsTable])
```

Comment: > Runs the supplied procedure (via reduce), for purposes of side
effects, on successive items in the collection. Returns nil

Comment: Without proper type hints this solution will force Clojure to use reflections.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Thanks, fixed that